# How can Jasmine use FormGroup super constructor when called in ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, typeerror

I have defined my own form class which extends FormGroup with the following constructor:

```
public constructor(/* params */) {
    function myValidator(): ValidatorFn {
      //return validator function
    }

    super({ /* controls */}, [myValidator()]);
  }
```

When I run my app it works, however when I run a unit test for it, it breaks on the super constructor and I get the following error message:

> TypeError: Class constructor FormGroup cannot be invoked without 'new'

It's constructed in my ngOnInit function of the component, like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new MyForm(/* args */);
    //call service
  }
```

My spec file:

```
let component: MyComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

const myArray = ['object'];
let myServiceMock: any;
let getCallSpy: any;

describe('ErdwwLoggingComponent', () => {

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    myServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['getCall']);
    getCallSpy = myService.getCall.and.returnValue( of(myArray) );

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MyService, useValue: myServiceMock }
      ]
    });

    TestBed.overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
      remove: {
        templateUrl: './my.component.html'
      },
      add: {
        template: '<div>test</div>'
      }
    });

    TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
  }));

  //succeeds
  it('should have spies defined', () => {
    expect(myServiceMock.getCall).toBeDefined('myServiceMock.getCall not defined');
    expect(getCallSpy).toBeDefined('getCallSpy not defined');
  });

  describe('initialisation', () => {
    //succeeds
    it('should be defined', () => {
      expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });

    //fails
    it('should call getCall', () => {
      // I also tried explicitly calling component.ngOnInit();
      fixture.detectChanges(); // onInit()

      expect(myServiceMock.getCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my tsconfig.spec.json file.

In `compilerOptions` I had `"target": "es5"`, when I removed that I no longer get the error.